# Update ng-repeat after ng-resource call is finished

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

I am using ngResource in combination with `ng-repeat` and noticed that slow REST calls doesn't update the list properly. It keeps empty.

As far as I understood I need a binding between controller and `ng-repeat` element.

My resource and controller definition:

```
(function (configure) {
    configure('loggingResource', loggingResource);

    function loggingResource($resource, REST_CONFIG) {
        return {
            Technical: $resource(REST_CONFIG.baseUrl + REST_CONFIG.path + '/', {}, {
                query: {
                    method: 'GET',
                    isArray: true
                }
            })
        };
    }
})(angular.module('loggingModule').factory);

(function (configure) {
    configure('logController', logController);

    function logController(loggingResource) {
        var that = this;
        loggingResource.Technical.query(function (data) {
            that.logs = data;
        });
        //that.logs = loggingResource.Technical.query();
    }
})(angular.module('loggingModule').controller);
```

ng.repeat usage:

```
<tr class="table-row" ng-repeat="log in logController.logs">
```

What I have tried so far:

- `ng-bind` in combination with `ng-repeat`
- `$q` with deferrer
- `$promise` of ngResource

What did I miss?

My try to get it on plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/t1c5Pxi7pzgocDMDNITX

Comment: Try to add `that.logs = [];` before calling the API.

Comment: Doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `{{}}` provides a default binding between your controller and view and you don't need to add anything explicitly. I have updated your plunkr with some minor changes to injected constants etc. and it is working.

```js
// Code goes here
angular.module("loggingModule", ['ngResource']);

(function(configure) {
  configure('loggingResource', loggingResource);

  function loggingResource($resource) {
    return {
      Technical: $resource('https://api.github.com/users/addi90/repos', {}, {
        query: {
          method: 'GET',
          isArray: true
        }
      })
    };
  }
})(angular.module('loggingModule').factory);

(function(configure) {
  configure('logController', logController);

  function logController(loggingResource) {
    var that = this;
    that.logs = [{
      title: 'test2'
    }];
    loggingResource.Technical.query(function(data) {
      that.logs = data;
    });
    //that.logs = loggingResource.Technical.query();
  }
})(angular.module('loggingModule').controller);
```

Since the api resource was not working, I have used my github repo api link there

The updated working plunkr is available here: https://plnkr.co/edit/cederzcAGCPVzc5xTeac?p=preview

Comment: btw since this is a resource you can just write `that.logs = loggingResource.Technical.query();`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
that.logs.push(data)
```

so you prevent to reinitialise the logs list. If you override the logs list and the ng-repeat is initialised before the logs list it seems to not be resolved.
Your logs list is set correctly after the rest call?

Comment: the binding between ng-repeat and the controller is done automatically, as angular uses two-way binding here